# How to get rid of annoying HorizontalContentAlignment binding warning?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I am working on a large WPF project and during debug my output window is filled with these annoying warnings:

> System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid > fallback value exists; using default instead. 
>   **BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null;** target element is 
>   '**ComboBoxItem**' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type >' 
>   HorizontalAlignment')

In the specific example ComboBoxItem is styled in this way:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>                  
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Border 
                    Name="bd"
                    Padding="4,4,4,4"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                    CornerRadius="2,2,2,2">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background"  Value="{StaticResource MediumBrush}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Padding"  Value="4,4,4,4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="CornerRadius"  Value="2,2,2,2"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I know that the problem is generated by the default theme definition for **ComboBoxItem** that contains things like:

```
<Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding Path="HorizontalContentAlignment" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl, AncestorLevel=1}" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

but I also thought that using

```
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
```

would taken care of the problem, and instead warnings are still there.

**EDIT: In order to reproduce the problem you need to override also the style of ComboBox exactly like done in this example from MSDN:
[ComboBox ControlTemplate Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28VS.85%29.aspx)**

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with this XAML neither in 4.0 nor in 3.5. It runs fine without any binding warnings.

Comment: you are right, I tested alone and it doesn't give me warning, I edit the question for more details

Comment: I cannot see that problematic binding in the example you linked in edit.

Comment: To see that kind of warnings you have to set the level of messages that appear. If set to all then this is usual. This can be changed in app.config file.

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me.  Put this in your Application.xaml file.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

from...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/42cd1554-de7a-473b-b977-ddbd6298b3d0

Comment: In case I'm not the only one who thought the style could go in any of the usual places - like the element itself, or its parent window/user control, etc - and failed to fix it, I want to point out that for some reason unknown to me, it only works in Application.Resources (as shown in this answer).

Comment: andrew's comment is right!! I had the same problem with ComboBoxes ...
Too bad that I noticed the comment too late and only after having put those lines in a ResourceDictionary, in the ComboBox, in <Window.Resources>, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if after more than a year your are still interested in this problem but my solution was to explicitly write in the style the value for this. For example:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
```

And that simply solved that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to mention I struggled with a similar problem for two days (mine was a "Windows Data Error 4" error, complaining about `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment`).

The most common suggested solution (adding the Horizontal/VerticalContentAlignment Style to your element, or even to the App.xaml) does NOT always solve the problem.

Eventually, I discovered something unique to my own situation - I hope it can be of help to someone: **If you are using the `FilterEventHandler`, don't unsubscribe it before resubscribing!**

My old code kept on generating that "Data Error 4" message whenever I changed the Channel Filter (which calls `UpdateCorporatesList`):

```cs
// This code generates errors
private void UpdateCorporatesList()
{
    this.CorporatesViewSource.Filter -= new FilterEventHandler(ApplyCorporateFilter);

    if (this.ChannelFilter != null)
    {
        this.CorporatesViewSource.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(ApplyCorporateFilter);
    }
    else
    {
        this.CorporateFilter = null;
    }
}

private void ApplyCorporateFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    SalesCorporate customer = e.Item as SalesCorporate;
    var currentChannel = this.Channels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == this.ChannelFilter).Description;
    if ((customer.ID != null) && (customer.Channel != currentChannel))
    {
        e.Accepted = false;
    }
}
```

...so I changed it to re-subscribe to the FilterEventHandler every time, and rather put the check for a null on Channel Filter in the event-handling method.

```cs
// This code works as intended
private void UpdateCorporatesList()
{
    this.CorporatesViewSource.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(ApplyCorporateFilter);

    if (this.ChannelFilter == null)
    {
        this.CorporateFilter = null;
    }
}

private void ApplyCorporateFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    var currentChannel = this.Channels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == this.ChannelFilter);
    if (currentChannel.ID == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    SalesCorporate customer = e.Item as SalesCorporate;
    if ((customer.ID != null) && (customer.Channel != currentChannel.Description))
    {
        e.Accepted = false;
    }
}
```

Et Voila! No more errors :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can't set style in App.Resources (because of the way program is built) and other solutions didn't work for me. However, I found the other way:

- Never set combobox source to null
- Instead when refreshing clear the collection and add items to it one by one
- Make sure to use ObservableCollection instead of List keep your UI updated