# ComboBoxItem continues to throw binding error despite style

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, datatemplate

I have a combobox that I am populating via a CollectionViewSource.  The items are build though a datatemplate for the incoming item type (in this case a ProjectViewModel).  This is in WPF in .NET 4.0.

In my window.resources, I have specified the following:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
```

Despite this style, I am still getting the following errors:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
> reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
> AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl',
> AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment;
> DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBoxItem' (Name=''); target
> property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
> reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
> AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl',
> AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment;
> DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBoxItem' (Name=''); target
> property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')

I have specified the Horizontal and Vertical ContentAlignment on the ComboBox element as well, to no avail.  This is not a terrible problem as the items appear correctly.  however when debugging, I do get about a 10 second delay when closing the window while it outputs about 4000 error messages to the output window (which I need open to catch legitimate binding errors.

I may not be reading the error correctly.  Why can it not find a valid source for the binding?  As far as I know, the way I am using the ComboBox and CollectionViewSource is in line with their intent.

Comment: I think someone fixed this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666439/how-to-get-rid-of-annoying-horizontalcontentalignment-binding-warning

Comment: @DJBurb The two suggestions in that question are essentially the same as the style that I have in my solution.  I have tried the style at the app.xaml level, and I have tried naming it as the type name aslo.  No changes.  Something strange is afoot at the Circle K.

Comment: I found that having the style in the app.xaml was the only way it would work. It didn't work on the element (the combo-box), the parent of the combo-box, the user-control, the window...

Answer (score 7):

I'd thought I'd solved this problem in my own program, but found that it kept popping up intermittently.  Finally managed to track down the source of the issue.

If you're using a combobox backed by an `ICollectionView`, and you stack two or more `collectionView.Refresh()` calls on the event queue (ie: calling refresh twice because of two different cleanup operations, for example), that will cause it to generate the binding error spam on each element of the combobox for each additional `Refresh()` call made.  This binding error will only occur after you have opened the combobox at least once.

Rewriting it so that you only call `Refresh()` once for a given event will prevent the binding error from popping up.

Comment: I only had one manual refresh call in my code, but removing it got rid of all these error messages. Thanks for this solution!

Comment: I had a similar issue where the collection that I was using for the items source was being updated/changed frequently, which was the cause of my problems.  I can't confirm it, but I wouldn't be surprised if Refresh() got called somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to mention I struggled with this problem for two days. The most common suggested solution (adding the Horizontal/VerticalContentAlignment Style to your element, or even to the App.xaml) does NOT always solve the problem.

Eventually, I discovered something unique to my own situation - I hope it can be of help to someone: **If you are using the FilterEventHandler, don't unsubscribe it before resubscribing!**

My old code kept on generating that "Data Error 4" message whenever I changed the Channel Filter (which calls UpdateCorporatesList):

```
// This code generates errors
private void UpdateCorporatesList()
{
    this.CorporatesViewSource.Filter -= new FilterEventHandler(ApplyCorporateFilter);

    if (this.ChannelFilter != null)
    {
        this.CorporatesViewSource.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(ApplyCorporateFilter);
    }
    else
    {
        this.CorporateFilter = null;
    }
}

private void ApplyCorporateFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    SalesCorporate customer = e.Item as SalesCorporate;
    var currentChannel = this.Channels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == this.ChannelFilter).Description;
    if ((customer.ID != null) && (customer.Channel != currentChannel))
    {
        e.Accepted = false;
    }
}
```

...so I changed it to re-subscribe to the FilterEventHandler every time, and rather put the check for a null on Channel Filter in the event-handling method.

```
// This code works as intended
private void UpdateCorporatesList()
{
    this.CorporatesViewSource.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(ApplyCorporateFilter);

    if (this.ChannelFilter == null)
    {
        this.CorporateFilter = null;
    }
}

private void ApplyCorporateFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    var currentChannel = this.Channels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == this.ChannelFilter);
    if (currentChannel.ID == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    SalesCorporate customer = e.Item as SalesCorporate;
    if ((customer.ID != null) && (customer.Channel != currentChannel.Description))
    {
        e.Accepted = false;
    }
}
```

Et Voila! No more errors :-)

Answer (score 2):

Struggled with this error for few hours, tried every solution from google, only this one worked, remove OverridesDefaultStyle property line from your combobox style:

```
// before
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />

// after
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
```

Using style template for combobox inside datagrid cell
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need help on this, but I just figured out a way to make this error/warning disapear.
In my combobox, I redefined the ItemTemplate property like this :

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemContainerTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=YourBinding}"/>
    </ItemContainerTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

YourBinding is the value you would use as the "DisplayMemberPath" for the ComboBox

Comment: I have long since finished that project, and don't readily have access to the source.  I *think* I had a custom ItemTemplate, but I am not sure.  Unfortunately, it is like to be months (if ever) before I get back on that project again and can check.