# WPF ComboBox Errors with Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm new to C# and I keep getting the errors below which I can't remove.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'RibbonGalleryItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'RibbonGalleryItem' (Name=''); target property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')
```

My code is below and I can't tell exactly which line is causing the error but I suspect it's related to the RibbonRadioButtons as, if I remove them, I don't get errors. The errors only appear after clicking on two or more radio buttons. An answer at [ComboBoxItem continues to throw binding error despite style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070861/comboboxitem-continues-to-throw-binding-error-despite-style) suggested it was multiple Refresh() statements causing the problem but I can't see how to avoid this.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

XAML

```
<Grid>
  <DockPanel>
    <r:Ribbon DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="Ribbon" SelectedIndex="0">
      <r:RibbonGroup Header="Continent" Width="Auto">
        <r:RibbonComboBox x:Name="CountryList" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
          <r:RibbonGallery x:Name="cbSelectedCountry" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCountry, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="DisplayName" >
            <r:RibbonGalleryCategory x:Name="cbCountryList" ItemsSource="{Binding CountryView}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" />
          </r:RibbonGallery>
        </r:RibbonComboBox>
        <WrapPanel>
          <r:RibbonRadioButton x:Name="All" Label="All" GroupName="ContinentGroup"
                    Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=All}">
          </r:RibbonRadioButton>
          <r:RibbonRadioButton x:Name="Africa" Label="Africa" GroupName="ContinentGroup"
                    Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=Africa}">
          </r:RibbonRadioButton>
          <r:RibbonRadioButton x:Name="America" Label="America" GroupName="ContinentGroup"
                    Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=America}">
          </r:RibbonRadioButton>
        </WrapPanel>
      </r:RibbonGroup>
    </r:Ribbon>
  </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
public class MySettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Country> countries;
    private ContinentViewModel selectedContinent;
    private static string selectedCountry;
    private int selectedRadioGroup;
    private ObservableCollection<ContinentViewModel> continents;
    private ListCollectionView countryView;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private bool _All;
    private bool _Africa;
    private bool _America;

    public MySettings()
    {
        countries = new ObservableCollection<Country>(
            new[]
            {
                new Country() { Continent = Continent.Africa, DisplayName = "Algeria" },
                new Country() { Continent = Continent.Africa, DisplayName = "Egypt" },
                new Country() { Continent = Continent.Africa, DisplayName = "Chad" },
                new Country() { Continent = Continent.Africa, DisplayName = "Ghana" },
                new Country() { Continent = Continent.America, DisplayName = "Canada" },
                new Country() { Continent = Continent.America, DisplayName = "Greenland" },
                new Country() { Continent = Continent.America, DisplayName = "Haiti" }
            });
        CountryView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(countries);
        CountryView.Filter += CountryFilter;
        Continents = new ObservableCollection<ContinentViewModel>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Continent)).Cast<Continent>().Select(c => new ContinentViewModel { Model = c }));
    }

    public bool All
    {
        get => _All;
        set
        {
            _All = value;
            CountryView.Refresh();
            SelectedCountry = _All ? countries.FirstOrDefault().DisplayName : SelectedCountry;
            OnPropertyChanged("All");
        }
    }

    public bool Africa
    {
        get => _Africa;
        set
        {
            _Africa = value;
            CountryView.Refresh();
            SelectedCountry = _Africa ? countries.Where(_ => _.Continent == Continent.Africa).FirstOrDefault().DisplayName : SelectedCountry;
            OnPropertyChanged("Africa");
        }
    }

    public bool America
    {
        get => _America;
        set
        {
            _America = value;
            CountryView.Refresh();
            SelectedCountry = _America ? countries.Where(_ => _.Continent == Continent.America).FirstOrDefault().DisplayName : SelectedCountry;
            OnPropertyChanged("America");
        }
    }

    private bool CountryFilter(object obj)
    {
        var country = obj as Country;
        if (country == null) return false;
        if (All && !Africa && !America) return true;
        else if (!All && Africa && !America) return country.Continent == Continent.Africa;
        else if (!All && !Africa && America) return country.Continent == Continent.America;
        return true;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ContinentViewModel> Continents
    {
        get => continents;
        set
        {
            continents = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Continents");
        }
    }

    public ListCollectionView CountryView
    {
        get => countryView;
        set
        {
            countryView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CountryView");
        }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public Continent Continent { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Continent
    {
        All,
        Africa,
        America
    }

    public class ContinentViewModel
    {
        public Continent Model { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName => Enum.GetName(typeof(Continent), Model);
    }

    public ContinentViewModel SelectedContinent
    {
        get => selectedContinent;
        set
        {
            selectedContinent = value;
            OnContinentChanged();
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedContinent");
        }
    }

    private void OnContinentChanged()
    {
        CountryView.Refresh();
    }

    public int SelectedRadioGroup
    {
        get => selectedRadioGroup;
        set
        {
            selectedRadioGroup = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRadioGroup");
        }
    }

    public string SelectedCountry
    {
        get => selectedCountry;
        set
        {
            if (selectedCountry == value) return;
            selectedCountry = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCountry");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using x:Name everywhere? That's a code smell

Comment: They were used to help debug the XAML.

Comment: Fair enough, I had a similar problem and it turned out to be a rogue style that would try to apply it self. Try using Style="{x:Null}" on the `RadioButton` and see if you still get the errors.

Comment: It didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I used mvvmlight and made some changes to simplify your code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <Ribbon DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="Ribbon" SelectedIndex="0">
            <RibbonGroup Header="Continent" Width="Auto">
                <RibbonComboBox x:Name="CountryList" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                    <RibbonGallery x:Name="cbSelectedCountry" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <RibbonGalleryCategory x:Name="cbCountryList" ItemsSource="{Binding CountryView}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" />
                    </RibbonGallery>
                </RibbonComboBox>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <RibbonRadioButton x:Name="All" Label="All" GroupName="ContinentGroup" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="{Binding Path=All}"></RibbonRadioButton>
                    <RibbonRadioButton x:Name="Africa" Label="Africa" GroupName="ContinentGroup" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Africa}"></RibbonRadioButton>
                    <RibbonRadioButton x:Name="America" Label="America" GroupName="ContinentGroup" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="{Binding Path=America}"></RibbonRadioButton>
                </WrapPanel>
            </RibbonGroup>
        </Ribbon>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

I created a property SelectedCountry of type Country to bind the combobox to, rather than setting a string like your code was doing.

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfTest.ViewModel
{
/// <summary>
/// This class contains properties that the main View can data bind to.
/// <para>
/// Use the <strong>mvvminpc</strong> snippet to add bindable properties to this ViewModel.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// You can also use Blend to data bind with the tool's support.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// See http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm
/// </para>
/// </summary>
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Country> countries;
    private ListCollectionView _countryView;

    public ListCollectionView CountryView
    {
        get { return _countryView; }
        set { this.Set(ref _countryView, value); }
    }

    private Country _SelectedCountry;
    public Country SelectedCountry
    {
        get { return _SelectedCountry; }
        set { this.Set(ref _SelectedCountry, value); }
    }

    private bool _All;
    public bool All
    {
        get { return _All; }
        set
        {
            this.Set(ref _All, value);
            CountryView.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private bool _Africa;
    public bool Africa
    {
        get { return _Africa; }
        set
        {
            this.Set(ref _Africa, value);
            if (SelectedCountry != null && SelectedCountry.Continent != Continent.Africa)
            {
                SelectedCountry = null;
            }
            CountryView.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private bool _America;
    public bool America
    {
        get { return _America; }
        set
        {
            this.Set(ref _America, value);
            if (SelectedCountry != null && SelectedCountry.Continent != Continent.America)
            {
                SelectedCountry = null;
            }
            CountryView.Refresh();
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        countries = new ObservableCollection<Country>(
        new[]
        {
            new Country() { Continent = Continent.Africa, DisplayName = "Algeria" },
            new Country() { Continent = Continent.Africa, DisplayName = "Egypt" },
            new Country() { Continent = Continent.Africa, DisplayName = "Chad" },
            new Country() { Continent = Continent.Africa, DisplayName = "Ghana" },
            new Country() { Continent = Continent.America, DisplayName = "Canada" },
            new Country() { Continent = Continent.America, DisplayName = "Greenland" },
            new Country() { Continent = Continent.America, DisplayName = "Haiti" }
        });
        CountryView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(countries);
        CountryView.Filter += CountryFilter;
        CountryView.Refresh();


        ////if (IsInDesignMode)
        ////{
        ////    // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
        ////}
        ////else
        ////{
        ////    // Code runs "for real"
        ////}
    }

    private bool CountryFilter(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Country c)
        {
            if (Africa && c.Continent != Continent.Africa)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (America && c.Continent != Continent.America)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

public enum Continent
{
    All,
    Africa,
    America
}

public class Country
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public Continent Continent { get; set; }
}
}
```

I don't get the binding errors you were having, but my datacontext is being set from the locator created by mvvmlight.

If your code is being used inside of a usercontrol, you can change this by taking the grid and moving it inside a usercontrol (without the datacontext line) and having it derive from the parents datacontext.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to avoid installing additional toolkits but I tried your code, replacing `this.Set(ref _Africa, value)` with `_Africa = value; OnPropertyChanged("Africa");` and the same for other instances of this.Set. Unfortunately, after selecting a button, this resulted in the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` at `if (SelectedCountry.Continent != Continent.Africa)`. Also the ComboBox is initially empty until the All button is pressed.

Comment: I fixed the problems, the combobox will not be empty and just added a check for SelectedCountry not being null.  Were you still getting the binding errors outside of that?

Comment: I added your changes to my code and Error 4 is still present though the ComboBox is initially populated. After clicking on two buttons there are 14 errors, one for each `Path=HorizontalContentAlignment` and `Path=VerticalContentAlignment` of each item in the collection. Also if I select an item then click another button whose list doesn't contain the new item then `namespace.MySettings+Country` appears in the ComboBox.

Comment: There must be some other code that you are not showing here.  How is your datacontext being set? Do you have any global styles set?

Comment: In MainWindow.xaml.cs I have `public MySettings mySettings = new MySettings(); public MainWindow() {InitializeComponent(); DataContext = mySettings;}` and in the XAML before <Grid> `<RibbonWindow.DataContext> <local:MySettings/> </RibbonWindow.DataContext>`. I don't have any styles set.